# What species of insect is this, spotted south-east of Berlin? Habitat: forest near lake shore, Size: body 40mm, w/o antennas and ovipositor

Tags: zoology, entomology, wasps

This insect has been spotted south-east of Berlin (2021-10-31).

[image: insect]

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include as much of the following essential information to improve your chances of getting a good answer: 1) habitat information; and 2) an estimate of the size of the organism. ——— Please see the [tour] and the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site for details.

Comment: does [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/100964/is-this-a-hornet/100965#100965) your question?

Comment: For starters, looks like in the family ichneumonidae

Comment: I found a picture on the internet with a resembling insect that was specified as Rhyssa persuasoria. But when I looked this species up it shows a much darker color (black). This is puzzling me. Also bob1's response points to a species of the same shape but different color.

Comment: @VolkerOtto there will be some natural variation in colour within the species. At best you could probably say *Rhyssa* genus or perhaps the closely related *Megarhyssa*, but I think those have some brown/red in them rather than just black and yellow/white.

Comment: There's a nice PDF guide to the british species of wasps etc. [here](https://www.nhm.ac.uk/content/dam/nhmwww/take-part/identify-nature/british-ichneumonid-wasps-id-guide.pdf) I'd expect similar species in most of Western Europe, though maybe not the exact species.

Comment: @bob1 thank you very much for sharing this guide and your profound answers - very helpful.

Comment: You can try uploading the image to iNaturalist.org . Very good site for getting help on species id.