# What insect is this? Found in a dying tree

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps

I recently found this insect near where I live, where my childs play always! Is it dangerous ??. What insect is this ? Is it poisonous?

Its about 3cm
Picture:
[image]

[image]

I live in Montreal, Quebec, Canada

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Can you [edit] what the 3 cm is measuring into your post? (e.g.s: head to tip of abdomen vs. tips of antennae to tip of the ovipositor, which is the "drill" sticking into the wood). If you can specify the type of tree that you found it on that could also help. ——— This wasp is likely only dangerous to the wood boring larvae she is trying to lay eggs in, but we can't give health advice on this site. At any rate if you (and your children) don't harass her, she'll most likely pay you no attention at all.

Comment: Looks like some kind of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitoid_wasp Maybe even the species in the first example picture

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I saw ! Thanks for the response!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is this a hornet?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/100964/is-this-a-hornet)

Answer (score 4):

From [Gil Wizen's page](https://gilwizen.com/megarhyssa/), it's a wasp.

> Giant ichneumon wasps (genus Megarhyssa) are some of the biggest North American wasps thanks to the females’ long (10cm) ovipositor, which is longer than the wasp’s own body. These wasps might look fierce but **they are actually shy and harmless insects**. They are parasitoids: their larvae develop as parasites living inside the body of other insects. The female’s ovipositor is therefore not a stinger, but an organ used to inject eggs into the larva’s host. (emphasis mine)

Here is one of his amazing photographs or the wasp laying eggs (into a dead tree).

[image]